# How do I make a function run when Python starts

Tags: python, function, import

I was wondering if there was a way to make functions run when python starts this is what I am currently doing:

```
def JC():
    print("Just Chill Coding Enviorment")

import JC_startup()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [main function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Asking%20for%20Help/Do%20you%20need%20a%20int%20main%28%29%20like%20you%20do%20in%20c%2B%2B), or you could just put it right at the top.

Comment: Thank you jnd I find that tip very helpful also if you are wondering why I dont know this is because I am 10 years old.